# Impressão não permite alteração da font pelo CSS

Tags: css, html5, google-chrome, impressão

[image: Imagem]

HTML:

```
    <div class="conteudotopo">
        <div class="container-logo">
            <img src="VX_LOGOTIPO"  height="30" />
        </div>
        <p>NF: 112233</p>
        <!-- <p>Pedido: 0</p> -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.conteudotopo{
margin: 2px;
flex: 1;
height:25mm;
font-size: 26px;
}
```

É possível ver em "NF: 112233" que mesmo com font-size: 26px, o tamanho dá fonte não é alterado.
*Tenho que usar o chrome*

Comment: tentou aplicar o style inline na sua tag? creio que assim vai.

Comment: Obrigado @EliseuB. Problema resolvido

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode forçar o estilo de impressão usando um media querie Print, tipo `@media print` diretamente no `<p> .conteudotopo > p`.  Aqui vc pode ler mais se te interessar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Responsive/Media_types

Dessa forma seu CSS ficaria dessa forma:

```
@media print {
    .conteudotopo > p {
        font-size: 26px !important;
    }
}
```